# Why does my GridSplitter not take full height

Tags: xaml

I have a `GridSplitter` but I can't make it stretch the full height of my app (my `UserControl` to be more precise). It only fills the same height as the content on the left/right of the `GridSplitter`.

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" /> <!--this was a trial and error thing-->
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" MinWidth="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" MinWidth="250" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="left" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <TextBlock Text="right" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Grid>
```

As I don't know the height, I was hoping for

This works in that the height is bigger, but it's not an acceptable approach as I don't know the size of the clients monitor.

But that isn't valid.

What do I need to do?

This is the parent

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="Orange">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Vm}" />
</StackPanel>
```

As you can see the background is orange, this gives me the bounds of the control. The control takes up all the room it can.

Comment: It looks like your problem is likely caused by the parent control of this grid. The grid control sizes to its parent. What is your user control contained within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `StackPanel` parent to a `Grid` control. The `StackPanel` control will size to its child elements. Use a `Grid` control instead, which will size to its parent control.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Orange">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Vm}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Actually I was able to simply remove the StackPanel and add the Grid.Row to the ContentPresenter. Thanks